# Can this DVD drive work without AHCI?

Tags: hardware, dvd

I have AHCI disabled in order to run a RAID driver, but when AHCI is disabled at startup, Linux can't see my DVD drive.

Can the DVD drive be made to still work without AHCI? Why does it need it?

Comment: What settings are available on your system? I’ve read elsewhere that Raid on SATA is AHCI. Perhaps enabling AHCI will allow both to work

Comment: Do you absolutely need hardware RAID? The Linux software RAID implementation doesn't really have that much overhead compared to hardware RAID, so I'd just enable AHCI, use Linux software RAID, and use your DVD.

Comment: Except on high-end server motherboards with built-in real HW raid controllers, motherboard raid is fake-raid, anyway, and absolute garbage compared to linux mdadm (or lvm or btrfs or zfs).   The only time it's useful is if/when you need to share a fake-raid array between linux & windows on a dual-boot system.  BTW, Even on high-end server motherboards, real HW raid is still garbage compared to mdadm/lvm/btrfs/zfs. HW raid was dying 15 years ago, it's long dead now.